# How to find out the width of a button in Vaadin 10?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

So I have three buttons like this.

[image: 3 Vaadin buttons in Lumo.DARK]

My goal is to make these buttons have same width. 
To do this I'd like to check each button width, put the largest value (in this case - 2nd button) in a variable and then make each button's width this value. 
I don't want to set the width using some magic number, because the text on my buttons may change.
I tried to do it like this:

```
String maxWidth = findMaxValue(button1.getWidth(), button2.getWidth(), button3.getWidth());
button1.setWidth(maxWidth);
button2.setWidth(maxWidth);
button3.setWidth(maxWidth);
```

The problem is `getWidth()` returns null if not set with the method `setWidth` in advance.
So, how do I find out width of the buttons?

Comment: Try using a `VerticalLayout` and `setHorizontalAlignment` to `STRETCH`.

Answer (score 7):

### Fix it with CSS

I get what you are trying to achieve, but I think that there are better ways to do this than measure box sizes. I think you could add a wrapping div around the buttons and a little css and let the browser take care for it.

For example flex-box should have solutions. Here's a quick test that I did.

```
<style>
  .my-layout {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
...   
<div class="my-layout">
  <vaadin-button>my button 1</vaadin-button>
  <vaadin-button>my very cool button 2</vaadin-button>
  <vaadin-button>b 3</vaadin-button>
</div>
```

Produces this:

[image: Equal width buttons]

[Live demo](https://excellent-panther.glitch.me/)

[Code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/excellent-panther?path=index.html:6:0)

### Getting the width of an rendered element

If you want the answer for the question that you asked originally, I think you can get it from the Element API with something like this:

```
button1.getElement().getProperty("offsetWidth",0);
```

but you might have to sync the properties, and they might not be available when you are originally rendering the elements as at that point they have no width. Consult the documentation for [Manipulating DOM with Element API](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/element-api/tutorial-properties-attributes.html) to learn more.